# Why Do I Get Unbound Local Error in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, error-handling

I was trying to make a sort of notepad with *tkinter*, which will include the ***Dark Mode*** feature.
My Code is:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x500')

#The menu
menu = Menu(window)

#The Dark mode function:
x = 1
fg = 'black'
def DM_toggle(var):
    if x%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    x+= 1



#The file menu
file = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
menu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)
file.add_cascade(label = 'New File ')
file.add_cascade(label = 'Save File')
file.add_separator()
file.add_cascade(label = ' EXIT ', command = window.destroy)

#the dark_mode button
dark_mode = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
menu.add_cascade(label = 'Dark Mode', menu = dark_mode)
dark_mode.add_checkbutton(label = ' Dark Mode', command =lambda: DM_toggle(x+1))

#The placing of menu
window.config(menu = menu)

window.mainloop()
```

And when i run the code and click the *dark mode* check-button,
I get this ***Unbound Local Error***:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:/Python tries#1/Note Pad try 2/notepad.py", line 34, in <lambda>
    dark_mode.add_checkbutton(label = ' Dark Mode', command =lambda: DM_toggle(x+1))
  File "F:/Python tries#1/Note Pad try 2/notepad.py", line 13, in DM_toggle
    if x%2 == 0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

How do I solve this Error?
I want to make the dark mode feature enabled!

Comment: Add a line `global x` within DM_toggle() to reference the global `x`. Otherwise the interpreter assumes it is a local variable (which you are reading without ever setting and therefore the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your `x` variable as global inside your function:

```
def DM_toggle(var):
    global x
    if x%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    x+= 1
```

Or pass it as a parameter:

```
def DM_toggle(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    x+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def DM_toggle(var):
    if x%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    x+= 1
```

When you update the value of a variable inside a function it becomes locked to local scope, so it won't check outside for a value of x. Since you don;t define x inside the function it's not defined when you try to update it, hence `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

What you need to do is make x global, that way it will use the x in the global scope. I'd also remove the var from the argument and change the command to just the function, since its just looking at and changing the global variable x.

```py
def DM_toggle():
    global x
    if x%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    x+= 1

... 

dark_mode.add_checkbutton(label = ' Dark Mode', command =DM_toggle)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#The Dark mode function:
x = 1
fg = 'black'
def DM_toggle(var):
    if var%2 == 0:
        window.config(bg = 'black')
        fg = 'white'
    else:
        window.config(bg = 'white')
        fg = 'black'
    var+= 1
```

Use `var` insted of `x` in `DM_toggle` function

Refer:
https://pythoncircle.com/post/680/solving-python-error-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-x-referenced-before-assignment/

Comment: This won't change the value of x outside the function. Given the way its called setting x as a global and removing var entirely is the way to go about it.

Comment: @FurtherReading here in that code ``x`` used only for that purpose.

Comment: @Parvat.R Please mark it as accepted as It worked for you

Comment: But it won't toggle. The global x will always be 1, so it will turn on darkmode but never turn it off.